# Need to send control from Action Class to JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, action

My code flow is as follows:

When the user is selecting a particular year from a  dropdown, the control goes to Javascript which takes the selected year and pass a particular URL.

```
function ModelForYear()
{

    var url = "modelforyear.do";
    var e = document.getElementById("yearId");
    var year = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    url = url + "?yearId=" + year ;
    document.location.href = url;

}
```

This URL is mapped to an action class for doing some calculation and setting a variable value. However, after the calculation, I want my control to go back to the calling JSP page without resetting the selected year(Specifically the control should go back not as a new request but part of same request).

I am using

```
return mapping.findForward("searchLabelData");
```

but it is going to jsp as a new request it seems

Could anyone help please....

Comment: Did you ever think of using Ajax, instead of `document.location.href`?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value back in the url

```
String url = mapping.findForward("searchLabelData").getPath()+"?yearId="+form.getYearId();
return new ActionForward(url, true);
```

Then use this parameter in the consumer to set the selected option value of the dropdown.